# Visualforce rendering woes - layout is broken when using a parent <apex:outputPanel>

Tags: visualforce, rerender, rendered, pageblocksection, outputpanel

I have a formatting issue caused by an extra output panel needed for rerendering on my visualforce page. The functionality works they way I have it now, but the formatting is ugly and I want to be able to have the fields aligned correctly.

Field #2 (Is License Requested...) controls whether or not fields 3, 4, 5, and 6 display (Account String, BU String, ect.) I want to be able to keep the structure of the visualForce page, but be able to succesfully get the other fields to dynamically display.

I should note:

- Rerendering the parent outputPanel of all of this markup works, but I'll lose my data in the top fields then.
- Rerendering the individual outputPanel ids (acctStringId and buStringId2) doesn't work. I need to include the testMeId in order for it to show up.

[image]

```
<!--field 1-->  <apex:inputField required="{!multiLicenseActivate}" value="{!User_Support__c.Business_Unit__c}" label="Business Unit"/>
<!--field 2-->  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:outputLabel value="Is License Requested for GCO User?" for="licReqGCOid"/>
                  <apex:actionRegion>
                    <apex:inputField id="licReqGCOid" required="{! (multiLicenseActivate==true && (User_Support__c.Salesforce_License__c==true || User_Support__c.Qvidian_License__c==true)) }" value="{!User_Support__c.Is_License_Requested_for_GCO_User__c}" >
                      <apex:actionSupport status="actStatusId2" event="onchange" rerender="testMeId,acctStringId,buStringId,dcId,ouStringId"/><!--manually rerendering the individual ids (acctStringId2, buStringId2) doesn't work without the parent outputPanel (testMeId).-->
                    </apex:inputField>
                  </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:outputPanel id="testMeId"><!--need this to successfully rerender the outputPanel-->
<!--field 3-->      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! User_Support__c.Is_License_Requested_for_GCO_User__c=='No' }" id="acctStringId">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Account String" for="acctStringId2"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="acctStringId2" required="{! (multiLicenseActivate==true && User_Support__c.Qvidian_License__c==true) }"  value="{!User_Support__c.Account_String__c}" label="Account String"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<!--field 4-->      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! User_Support__c.Is_License_Requested_for_GCO_User__c=='No' }" id="buStringId">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="BU String" for="buStringId2"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="buStringId2" required="{! (multiLicenseActivate==true && (User_Support__c.Salesforce_License__c==true || User_Support__c.Qvidian_License__c==true)) }" label="BU String" value="{!User_Support__c.BU_String__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: you can use <apex:panelgrid> for this type of scenarios, otherwise create a separate section to display all the fields, below to "Is License Requested for GCO User"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately if the Section items are not rendered the first time then they will not be rendered properly.

> Also note that `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` components can't be
>   rerendered; rerender the child components instead.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm

A work around is to rerender the page block itself with the downside being you will have a blank spot on the right but will get you closest to what you want would be as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="rerenderMe" reRender="thePageBlock"/>

        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <button type="button" onclick="rerenderMe();">Click Me</button>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="The Account" columns="2">

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel>Account Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!Account.Name = 'me'}">

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel>Billing Street</apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel>Billing State</apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingState}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>



            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

This would render properly except for leaving the empty spot on the right.

**On Load**
[image: On Load]

**Enter me and click button**
[image: Enter me and Click Button]

If you want everything to be in that spot on the right column the a panel grid would be the way to go (per comment from Santanu Boral)